# How to load multiple types in Fancybox 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, gallery

I use [Fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/), this is how I load my gallery (I disabled opening/closing animation so I load it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-fancybox-var]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var links = $('[data-fancybox-var]');
    var group = [];

    $.each(links, function( key, value ) {
        group.push({
            src  : value.href,
            opts : {
                caption : value.title
            }
        });
    });

    $.fancybox.open( group, {}, links.index( this ) );
});
```

I have 2 questions:
1. How can I disable/enable group easly (no counter)?
2. How can I load multiple types images/inline/iframe (it works only on images)?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by disable/enable group(no counter), generally you can easily group with `data-fancybox="group"` data attribute, and it will be grouped, otherwise it won't be.

Comment: thank you @azs06,I created 'data-fancybox-var' to load my content without the opening/closing animation instead of `data-fancybox="group"`, the code works perfectly, I only need to solve these two questions because my knowledge in js is basic..

Comment: It loads group even without `="group"`, this is not the result that i'm looking for.. I think there's something to do with the "group" thing in the code, I just copied it from another website...

Comment: Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMKRmO?editors=1010) to make it easy to understand

Comment: I see, the issue, if you don't want to group them, then instead of saving all links in an array, just open the clicked link. I will post a working example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @azs06, do you know how to slove my 2nd question?

Comment: I provided an example for external pdf files, you can see available media types and how to use them here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#media_types

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are saving all links in an array, and initiating fancybox on that array, so all links with `data-fancybox-var` would be grouped together. If you just want to open a link in fancybox then just initiate fancybox on that.

Example -

```js
$(function(){
 $('[data-fancybox-var]').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.fancybox.open(this);
 })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/9432166677_aefe32aad4_k_d.jpg" data-fancybox-var title="First image">
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/9432166677_61aa7e7f90_m_d.jpg">
</a>
<a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5499/30972532232_9c7db37049_k_d.jpg" data-fancybox-var>
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5499/30972532232_e9a298a0c5_m_d.jpg">
</a><br/>
<a data-fancybox-var data-src="http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf" href="javascript:;">
 Sample PDF
</a><br/>
<a data-fancybox-var data-src="#hidden-content" href="javascript:;">
Hidden div
</a> 
<div style="display: none;" id="hidden-content">
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>You are awesome.</p>
</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I also included an example of external pdf file, fancybox also supports video and iframes.

Comment: thank you again, the idea was to disable the opening/closing anim and open it just by fading, as you can see in my [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMKRmO?editors=1010), about the second question, I load my inline content with `href="#inline1"` but it's not working with this code :-(

Comment: I am not seeing any inline content in your example, could you update it?

Comment: @VadimL I updated my answer with inline content, please check.

Comment: I am trying to load SWF for example, here's my updated [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZMyax?editors=1010#anon-signup), take a look at "settings" to see how I load the flash (I use swfobject.js), it just opens another window if you click the SWF link

Comment: The way you are trying to load it should work, note, you are loading swf content from an non secured connection, most browsers will block it and most code playgrounds like jsbin, codepen also block it. You have to enable flash to see it in action. Working example http://run.plnkr.co/ReUfUIJYeDzY5Ibs/ http://plnkr.co/edit/jYFZvkRjn7RocvOdElLW?p=preview

Comment: thanks, about the inline flash, your solution works, about the security, you can see this [website](http://www.vldesign.co.il/banners_1_en.htm), how it handels flash content with divs and I'Ds and it works on every browser I checked, but your solution works too, only the animation is back, I tried to disable it like on my first example... sorry for the confusion... thank you for your patience...

Comment: You might have flash enabled for that website on your browsers, it doesn't work on firefox and chrome unless flash is enabled manually. I will recommend you to use alternative solution rather then using flash, as flash is disabled by default on all modern browsers.

Comment: We almost there.. :-) In your live snippet, if you click the pdf link or the hidden div, it opens without the animation (thumbnail zoom effect) **this is what I need for the images too**, it worked in my first [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMKRmO?editors=1010), maybe we should take some line from there but i'm not sure how to do it..? (but without grouping theme)

Comment: I couldn't find any way to permanently disable animation, but it's possible to decrease loading time to 30ms, which would disable animation virtually, also there aren't any major difference between your code and mine, just instead of an array here we are initiating the clicked image. Please check if this would work for you http://plnkr.co/edit/RoA9AGheu9GTVjQBcKu9?p=preview